# Why didn't the Commission order Hazel and Cha-Cha to protect Vanya at the very beginning?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

At the beginning of the Umbrella Academy, time-traveling assassins Hazel and Cha-Cha were given orders to eliminate Five, in order to ensure that the Apocalypse would happen. But the actual cause of the Apocalypse is

> Vanya,

and the Commission knew that.
 Still, they gave a misleading order that might have even killed

> Vanya(she was injured by Hazel when he and Cha-Cha ambushed the Academy mansion),

which have eventually stopped the Apocalypse from happening. So why didn't the Commission made their orders short and clear and told them to

> protect Vanya

in the first place?

Comment: At a guess, the pair are better adept at killing than protecting.

Comment: Yep. At one time, Hazel said that he just wanted to kill whoever he wanted instead of working on orders. Also, they weren't very good: near the end they complained that nobody ever told him Five had a family who were willing to fight at his side. Sigh.

Comment: The entire time travel aspect of the show is a bit confusing tbf - for instance, Hargreeves stages his death to bring the team together to avert the Apocalypse, but what bakes my noodle is that if he hadn't died at that point, Klaus wouldn't have had access to his study and so wouldn't have stolen the journal, so "Leonard" wouldn't have found out about Vanya and she would have continued believing she had no powers and taking her suppressants. Of course his aim could have been to reunite the team all along, but this is only another one of many examples that don't quite add up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because if Five didn't interfere, everything would progress correctly and the Apocalypse would occur. Protecting Vanya does not necessarily ensure the Apocalypse. Five could have found another way to change the timeline. So their initial order was to stop Five. Once it was clear they needed to change strategies, and they had a better idea what Five was up to, it was then feasible to simply protect Vanya.

Remember, The Commission likes to operate as subtly as possible to minimize the butterfly effect.

> **The Handler:** Now tell me, why unfortunate Karl?
>
> **Five:** Karl Weber is the butcher at the shop where Captain Ernst A. Lehmann acquires his weekly roast. So, if Karl dies, his butcher shop is passed on to his son Otto, who never washes his hands, which is disgusting. So he's the one who gives the captain his roast. And that gives him food poisoning. Which makes him late for work. Which delays the takeoff. And to make up for lost time, the Hindenburg flies through a weather front of high electrical charge and humidity. And the static electricity inside the aircraft makes it a virtual tinderbox. Tiny engine sparks And just like that, we have...
> <sub>*The Umbrella Academy - S01E06: The Day That Wasn't*</sub>

So naturally, their first plan was to remove the intruding element, before resorting to interfering in the timeline directly.